# Jenkins Master/Slave Windows

Tags: python, jenkins, centos

Just want a clarification of the following. I am currently in the process of transferring a Bamboo plan into a Jenkins one and everything was working fine up until the point I ran a Python script on my CentOS Virtual Machine. The reason being that Python wants to import a library called **winreg** which is not available on RedHat distributions.

In order to fix this, I wanted to have my Master be a CentOS machine and my slave be a Windows 10 machine. Is that how it works? Will the plan be built on the Windows 10 machine while the output is handled by the CentOS machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. This is usual Jenkins using - see [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).